# Create a dynamic link URL based on user info on input field

Tags: javascript, php, forms, hyperlink, location-href

I'm trying to make various input fields where visitors can enter a value and then hit go or submit to be redirected to a specific website.

Based on the info they entered they would be send to a specific link

For example if they enter Place: california, Day: 2, Month: 2, Year: 17, Id number: 234, and hit submit it would send them to http://www.example.com/california/2-2-17/234

I am no programmer but searching found this solution but with just one imput and was wondering if could be modified to work with the imputs described above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(e) {  
        var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
        window.location.replace(" http://www.example.com/page/"+inputvalue);

    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>

       <input type="text" value="11" id="input"> 
       <button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a working example for what you need

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="place" placeholder="Place" value="" id="place" required>
  <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="Day" value="" id="day" required>
  <input type="text" name="month" placeholder="Month" value="" id="month" required>
  <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Year" value="" id="year" required>
  <input type="text" name="id_number" placeholder="ID Number" value="" id="id_number" required>
  <button type="submit" id="button">Click Me!</button>
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/page/" + $("#place").val() + "/" + $("#day").val() + "-" + $("#month").val() + "-" + $("#year").val() + "/" + $("#id_number").val());
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**TLTR;**

- i change your html doctype declaration to HTML5 standard
- add required to all input for a minimum of validation to avoid wrong url generation. Here you can learn more about html5 validation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation (WARNING! these do not work on every browser version)
- put JS scripts on the bottom of the page to avoid it delaying loading of the page.

**ALTERNATIVE with calendar**

warning! html5 feature, not in all browser!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="place" placeholder="Place" id="place" required>
  <input type="date" name="calendar" placeholder="Date" id="calendar" required>
  <input type="number" name="id_number" placeholder="ID Number" id="id_number" required>
  <button type="submit" id="button">Click Me!</button>
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/page/" + $("#place").val() + "/" + $("#calendar").val().split("-").reverse().join("-") + "/" + $("#id_number").val());
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```